# If a list of object has matching elements from another list

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

I have a list of strings

```cs
List<string> listOfStrings = {"1","2","3","4"};
```

And I have a list of objects which looks like this

```cs
class Object A{
    string id;
    string Name;
}
```

How can I find all the objects which has matching list of strings.

I tried:

```cs
listOfA.Where(x => listoFstrings.Contains(x.id)).Select();
```

But it is not working, it is pulling all the other objects which doesn't have a matching string.

Comment: Your attempt seems correct. Can you post the data you tried it with?

Comment: Your logic is fine, it just the code that seems odd, empty `Select()` ?? List of string with `int` values. Can you add some real, compilable  code ?

Comment: Your line `listOfA.Where(x => listoFstrings.Contains(x.id)).Select();` would not compile, Also make sure you are assigning the result back to something, it will not change the original `listOfA`

Comment: Your current code generates the expression tree but you need to call "ToList()" or another method that'll perform eager execution of the code.  And as other's have states the ".Select()" statement shouldn't even compile as it's not valid.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a compilable, working version of your code:

```
// Specify list of strings to match against Id
var listOfStrings = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4" };

// Your "A" class
public class A
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// A new list of A objects with some Ids that will match
var listOfA = new List<A> 
{
    new A { Id = "2", Name = "A-2" },
    new A { Id = "4", Name = "A-4" },
};
```

Now you should be able to just about use your original code, except instead of `.Select()` I've used `.ToList()`:

```
// Search for A objects in the list where the Id is part of your string list
var matches = listOfA.Where(x => listOfstrings.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```